# Python list comprehension query

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

```
result = ['袁惟仁', None, 'Life']
# Replace None with empty string
response = ['' if s is None else s for s in result]
# Handle non-ascii characters
return [s.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(s, unicode) else str(s) for s in response]
```

In this code I'm replacing None values of list with '', then I handle Unicode characters. This works fine, but want to know if there is a better way to do it. Right now if I don't handle empty I get an error saying can't convert **None** to str.

Comment: Not really related, but I'm not sure `insinstance(s, unicode)` is doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: What version of Python are you on?

Comment: Python version 2.7.6

Comment: @PatrickHaugh has to be 2 because 3 doesn't have `unicode` type.

Comment: Anyway, your code runs without errors, so you are going to have to try to produce a MVCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same result you may get via using `or` with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> result = ['袁惟仁', None, 'Life']

>>> [r or '' for r in result]
['\xe8\xa2\x81\xe6\x83\x9f\xe4\xbb\x81', '', 'Life']
```

BTW, I don't get the part why you are explicitly doing `.encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: I think you're just misreading his question: He's asking for a better way to do it: he knows it works as written. I agree there is no need to explicitly tell it to encode it.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: And as per me it is the *better way* to do what he wants :) Suggestions to improve my answer are most welcomed.

Comment: That was directed at your now removed edit. The answer itself looks fine to me.

Comment: Oooops. After reading your comment I re-read the post and found that it was irrelevant. Was not knowing that you were referring the same. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

`filter(None, result)` will remove any `None`s from the list:

```
filter(None, result)
['\xe8\xa2\x81\xe6\x83\x9f\xe4\xbb\x81', 'Life']
```

Comment: I need to keep None and replace it with ''